# if an employee has salary of $7,800, the string “*******” would be inserted, and has salary of $3,100, the string “***”

Tags: oracle, plsql

Create a PL/SQL block that inserts an asterisk in the stars column for every whole $1,000 of an employee’s salary. For example, if an employee has salary of $7,800, the string `'*******'` would be inserted, and, if an employee has salary of $3,100, the string `'***'` would be inserted. Use the following code as a starting point.

```
   DECLARE
v_empid  new_emps.employee_id%TYPE := &employee_id ;
v_asterisk  new_emps.stars%TYPE := NULL;
 v_sal_in_thousands  new_emps.salary%TYPE;
BEGIN
 SELECT NVL(TRUNC(salary/1000), 0) INTO v_sal_in_thousands
 FROM  new_emps
 WHERE employee_id = v_empid;
 FOR i IN 1..v_sal_in_thousands LOOP
 v_asterisk:=v_asterisk||'*';
 UPDATE  new_emps SET stars = v_asterisk
 WHERE employee_id = v_empid;
 END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: If` v_asterisk` must consist of asterisks, why does the `lpad` function create a string of spaces, instead of a string of asterisks?

Comment: What is the purpose of PL/SQL here? This can be done with single update on the entire table.

Comment: @astentx - This is almost certainly a small exercise, for practice, in a first PL/SQL course. As such, it makes sense, as long as the instructor tells the students that in real life they wouldn't use PL/SQL for such easy SQL tasks. (One does, however, need to test new things on very small test cases first, before they can move on to the real applications of PL/SQL.) Too bad that most instructors don't say this to their students. In fact, even Oracle's own PL/SQL instructors often think doing such work in PL/SQL is perfectly fine. :-(

Comment: @astentx maybe you can teach me yeay???

Comment: @mathguy sorry I have been edited

Comment: @yiciyici There's a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66625567/2778710) with both PL/SQL and plain SQL code below. Single `update` statement in it is the way to do such update in real world, so PL/SQL should be used here only for demonstration/learning purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Title and text don't match.

Why are you left-padding an empty string with some more empty strings? Shouldn't have you used asterisks instead?

```
SQL> update test set
  2    stars = rpad('*', trunc(sal/1000), '*');

10 rows updated.

SQL> select * from test;

ENAME             SAL STARS
---------- ---------- ----------
SMITH             800
ALLEN            1600 *
WARD             1250 *
JONES            2975 **
MARTIN           1250 *
BLAKE            2850 **
SCOTT            3000 ***
TURNER           1500 *
ADAMS            1100 *
JAMES             950

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

As you requested: PL/SQL and a loop within:

```
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_e in (select ename, sal
  3                  from test
  4                 )
  5    loop
  6      update test set
  7        stars = rpad('*', trunc(cur_e.sal/1000), '*')
  8        where ename = cur_e.ename;
  9    end loop;
 10  end;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from test;

ENAME             SAL STARS
---------- ---------- ----------
SMITH             800
ALLEN            1600 *
WARD             1250 *
JONES            2975 **
MARTIN           1250 *
BLAKE            2850 **
SCOTT            3000 ***
TURNER           1500 *
ADAMS            1100 *
JAMES             950

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: sorry can you retype the code all I still don't understand, the question need looping for

Comment: Sure; have a look.

Comment: DECLARE   v_empno       new_emps.employee_id%TYPE := <employee_id>;   v_asterisk    new_emps.stars%TYPE := NULL;   v_sal_in_thousands  new_emps.salary%TYPE; BEGIN   SELECT NVL(TRUNC(salary/1000), 0) INTO v_sal_in_thousands     FROM new_emps WHERE employee_id = v_empno;   FOR …   … UPDATE new_emps     SET stars = v_asterisk     WHERE employee_id = v_empno; END;

Comment: sorry the question is Create a PL/SQL block that inserts an asterisk in the stars column for every whole $1,000 of an employee’s salary. For example, if an employee has salary of $7,800, the string “****” would be inserted, and, if an employee has salary of $3,100, the string “” would be inserted. Use the following code as a starting point. and add the query above

Comment: maybe you can help to add the query to make update because my query is still using ampersand

Comment: There's no sense in what you are saying. If you want to use a **parameter** (ampersand represents a substitution variable), then create a **stored procedure** instead of an anonymous PL/SQL block. Furthermore, it means that you're updating a **single record** - the one that belongs to employee whose name (or ID) you pass as a parameter. Therefore, you don't need any loop for this. Finally, I posted two pieces of code which should get you started. It's about time you do your own homework.

Comment: sorry because the question ask like that